# Confused about interface inheritance

Tags: vb.net, interface

I know I should use this much more widely, but our code only has a handful of Interfaces, so I'm a bit noob about them. Here's my problem. In file one I have this:

```
Friend Interface IDateRow
    Property Name() As String
    ...
End Interface
Friend Interface IAmountRow
    Property StartDate() As IDateRow
    Property EndDate() As IDateRow
    ...
End Interface
```

In file 2 I have this:

```
Friend Class DateRow
    Inherits DtaRow
    Implements IDateRow
    Friend Property Name() As String Implements IDateRow.Name
    ...
End Class
```

So far so good. Now...

```
Friend Class AmountRow
    Inherits DtaRow
    Implements IAmountRow
    Friend Property StartDate() As DateRow Implements IAmountRow.StartDate
```

This will not work - it says:

```
'StartDate' cannot implement 'StartDate' because there is no matching property on interface 'IAmountRow'.
```

Am I correct in thinking this is because it returns a DateRow and not a IDateRow? DateRow implements IDateRow, so it *seems* like it should be legal.

I know I'm missing something dumb here...

Comment: Are you moving the cursor to an empty line after typing `Implements IAmountRow` instead of using the Enter Key?  The VB IDE will auto-implement the interface upon hitting the Enter Key.  You can the change the default `Public` access modifier to `Friend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must implement the property with the exact same type as the interface - so

```
Friend Property StartDate() As DateRow Implements IAmountRow.StartDate
```

Should be

```
Friend Property StartDate() As IDateRow Implements IAmountRow.StartDate
```

Comment: Ok that is what I thought. But that seems to break the entire concept of inheritance and polymorphism. The "whole idea" of interfaces, as I see it, is that you can pass around any object that conforms, DateRow conforms, so why is this a problem?

Comment: No, but I can understand the confusion. It doesn't brake polymorphism, it's an example of polymorphism since the implementing properties are only obligated to provide an instance that implement the `IDataRow`, meaning they can return any instance that implements the `IDataRow` interface (whether directly or by inheritance) - but they can only do it as an `IDataRow`.

Comment: I understand. So I guess now I want to open another question, but I am confused by the terminology. I think you understand what I am trying to do, how would you describe that task?

Answer (score 0):

Interface is an identity. Let's assume that IDateRow is placed in "A.dll" and DateRow that implemets it is in "B.dll". And lets assume that there is a function in A.dll that inputs an IDateRow instance. Since A.dll does not reference B.dll, it does not know what DateRow is. So it expects an instance that has a "Property StartDate() As IDateRow" not a DateRow.

**Edit** - My attempt to answer @MauryMarkowitz's comment:

I think an abstract class is what you want. I've written an example in c#, but I guess its similar in vb.

```
//A.dll -> has no reference
public abstract class Vehicle 
{
    public abstract double Mass();
    public abstract double Force();

    public double Acceleration()
    {
        return this.Force() / this.Mass();
    }
}
public interface ICar
{
    double MaxGroundSpeed();
}
public interface IPlane
{
    double MaxAirSpeed();
}


//B.dll -> has a reference to A.dll
public class Ferrari360 : Vehicle, ICar
{
    public override double Force()
    {
        return 400;
    }
    public override double Mass()
    {
        return 1350;
    }
    public virtual double MaxGroundSpeed()//Ferrari likes to make good cars, better, so this should be virtual.
    {
        return 282;
    }
}
public class Ferrari360GT:Ferrari360
{
    public override double Mass()
    {
        return 1100;
    }
    public override double MaxGroundSpeed()
    {
        return 300;
    }
}
public class Concorde : Vehicle, IPlane
{
    public override double Force()
    {
        throw new ClassifiedInformationException();
    }
    public override double Mass()
    {
        return 92080;
    }
    public double MaxAirSpeed()
    {
        return 2180;
    }
}
public class DeLoreanTimeMachine : Vehicle, ICar, IPlane
{
    public override double Force()
    {
        return 130;
    }
    public override double Mass()
    {
        return 1230;
    }
    public double MaxAirSpeed()
    {
        return 299792;
    }
    public double MaxGroundSpeed()
    {
        return 88;
    }
}
```

An example use:

```
Ferrari360 greatCar = new Ferrari360();
Console.WriteLine(greatCar.Acceleration());
```

Comment: Sorry for my tardy reply... so then I'm just doing this wrong. My goal is to have a definition in A and different concrete implementations in B, C and D. There are functions in A that operate on the definition, so how do I implement these in, say, B, such that they can be called in A? I guess through subclasses or partials?